# set background image dynamically on sidenavigationpanel

Tags: codenameone

I am using sidemenu in my main form, but would like to change the background image dynamically when returning to mainform.

How do I change the background image on sidenavigationpanel in run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach I can think of is theme layering. First make sure to define an image to the `SideNavigationPanel` UIID so it works.

When you want to replace that image do this:

```
HashMap layer = new HashMap();
layer.put("SideNavigationPanel.bgImage", myNewImage);
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(layer);
currentForm.refreshTheme();
```